# Spring security redirect when maximum sessions for this principal exceeded

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

So user login **->** closes the browser **->** opens browser one more time **->** error appears:

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded
```

What I need is to capture this event that session is invalid, remove all sessions for this user and redirect to normal login page

spring security config:

```
        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
                <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
                    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
                </session-management>   
                <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" requires-channel="any"/> 

    <!--<custom-filter after="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="sessionExpiration" /> -->
    <!-- .... -->

        </http>

<beans:bean id="sessionExpiration" class="com.test.security.SessionExpirationFilter">
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl">
            <beans:value>/login</beans:value>
        </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>
```

I tried to implement some filter, but it always shows that session is null:

```
public class SessionExpirationFilter implements Filter, InitializingBean {
    private String expiredUrl;

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String path = httpRequest.getServletPath();
        HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(false);

        System.out.println(session);
        if (session == null && !httpRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {              
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            String targetUrl = httpRequest.getContextPath()
                    + expiredUrl;
            httpResponse.sendRedirect(httpResponse.encodeRedirectURL(targetUrl));
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void setExpiredUrl(String expiredUrl) {
        this.expiredUrl = expiredUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to invalidate the previous session if it User's session exceeds 'max-sessions'. Set the property 'error-if-maximum-exceeded' to false. Spring security automatically invalidates previous session.

If you are trying to do something different,

1. Extend ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy class, and override
   'allowableSessionsExceeded' method.
2. Specify the bean reference of the above as 'session-authentication-strategy-ref' attribute value of 'session-management'

.

Comment: I have set `error-if-maximum-exceeded` to `false`. when I tried to login multiple times then newest session will invalidate previous session. But, *what if I have to maintain 1st session & don't allow to login again until 1st logout done ?* Do u have any idea how this can be achieved ?

Comment: @OO7 You need to set that property to `true`  then the second session will not be allowed
`error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"`

Comment: @OO7 you can use something like maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"` will allow the second session and invalidate the first one as your `max-sessions="1"`

If you have `max-sessions="2"` then it will allow the `Nth` session also and invalidate all `N-2` sessions

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"/>
</session-management>
```

Setting `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"` will `NOT` allow the second session and invalidate the second session as your `max-sessions="1"`

If you have `max-sessions="2"` then it will not allow the `2+` sessions and invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers above

> Spring security automatically invalidates previous session

if you want to redirect the user on login page, you can add

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login.html">
    ...
</session-management>
```

Since the previous session is already invalidated.

---

I have also read in your comment above that you may want to retain the previous session when you try to login again. This defeats your first question, but anyways.

are you talking about [7. Session Fixation Protection with Spring Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)

> The framework offers protection against typical Session Fixation
>   attacks by configuring what happens to an existing session when the
>   user tries to authenticate again:
>
> `<session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">`
>
> The corresponding Java configuration:
>
> `http.sessionManagement().sessionFixation().migrateSession()`
>
> By default, Spring Security has this protection enabled
>   (“migrateSession“) – on authentication a new HTTP Session is created,
>   the old one is invalidated and the attributes from the old session are
>   copied over.
>
> If this is not the desired behavior, two other options are available:
>
> when `“none”` is set, the original session will not be invalidated
>
> when `“newSession”` is set, a clean session will be created without any of
>   the attributes from the old session being copied over

Answer (score -1):

```html
<session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1"/>
        <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Fyi, if anyone comes across this - ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy appears to be deprecated in favor of ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.